# java rest returning response with json to postman - syntax error: unexpected 'S'

Tags: java, json, rest, postman

When using postman, i get the following error

**Syntax error: unexpected 'S'**

even though my JSON String seems fine. I have looked on similar topics, that typically says to give the response object an entity that can be properly converted to JSON. I have parsed a List of pets with GSON.

Code:

```
@Path("Pet")
public class PetResource {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    public PetResource() {
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getJson() {
        PetMapper pm = new PetMapper();
        JSONConverter jsonconv = new JSONConverter();
        List<Pet> petList = pm.getPets();
        String json = jsonconv.getJsonFromPets(petList);
        return Response.ok().entity(json).build();
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("/size")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getPetSize() {
        PetMapper pm = new PetMapper();
        return Response.ok(pm.getPetSize()).build();
    }
}
```

GSon Converter

```
public class JSONConverter {

    static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

public String getJsonFromPets(List<Pet> pets) {
    String petsString = "";
    for (Pet pet : pets) {
        petsString += gson.toJson(pet) + " ";
    }
    return petsString;
}
}
```

The following is my Raw Response

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Fiddo",
  "birth": "2015-02-01",
  "species": "Dog",
  "owner_id": 1,
  "events": []
} {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Hannibal",
  "birth": "2013-05-10",
  "species": "Dog",
  "owner_id": 1,
  "events": []
} {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Elvis",
  "birth": "2010-08-08",
  "species": "Cat",
  "owner_id": 3,
  "events": []
} {
  "id": 4,
  "name": "Sam",
  "birth": "2012-01-05",
  "species": "Rabbit",
  "death": "2015-07-07",
  "owner_id": 2,
  "events": []
}
```

Comment: That means your response is not being sent as you expect. There's probably an exception in the framework, which causes some error content to be sent down. Can you check what the "Raw" response looks like?

Comment: I have edited my question, the json at the bottom is the raw response :)

Comment: Oh, yeah, it's not valid JSON. It's multiple objects not enclosed in a parent (object or array), and they aren't even separated with commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output text is not valid JSON. The problem is with how the list is being serialized.

I believe it should be enough to give your JSON library the entire list:

```
public String getJsonFromPets(List<Pet> pets) {
    return gson.toJson(pets);
}
```

Comment: I'll accept as answer in 5 minutes, thanks for your time. It works :)

Comment: @JonasGrønbek The best answer may still be on its way :-), take your time